# Is the sqlite database (the default django database) good enough?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am building this ecommerce app with django, and I was thinking if the default database (sqlite) was fine enough? My django app is going to have around 200 different products, and for payments I will use stripe API. I do not expect too much traffic when the app is up, since it's a website only for the country I live in with 6 million inhabitants. So can I settle with the sqlite database?

Answer (score 1):

Although your answer may seem opinion based, the right answer is no anyways. SQLite3 is a lightweight database, which is commonlu used when your project is small and you don't mind to start up a server.
SQLite comes with following advantages and disadvantages ([source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/sqlite-vs-mysql-vs-postgresql-a-comparison-of-relational-database-management-systems))

### Advantages of SQLite

**Small footprint:** As its name implies, the SQLite library is very lightweight. Although the space it uses varies depending on the system where it’s installed, it can take up less than 600KiB of space. Additionally, it’s fully self-contained, meaning there aren’t any external dependencies you have to install on your system for SQLite to work.

**User-friendly:** SQLite is sometimes described as a “zero-configuration” database that’s ready for use out of the box. SQLite doesn’t run as a server process, which means that it never needs to be stopped, started, or restarted and doesn’t come with any configuration files that need to be managed. These features help to streamline the path from installing SQLite to integrating it with an application.

**Portable:** Unlike other database management systems, which typically store data as a large batch of separate files, an entire SQLite database is stored in a single file. This file can be located anywhere in a directory hierarchy, and can be shared via removable media or file transfer protocol.

### Disadvantages of SQLite

**Limited concurrency:** Although multiple processes can access and query an SQLite database at the same time, only one process can make changes to the database at any given time. This means SQLite supports greater concurrency than most other embedded database management systems, but not as much as client/server RDBMSs like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

**No user management:** Database systems often come with support for users, or managed connections with predefined access privileges to the database and tables. Because SQLite reads and writes directly to an ordinary disk file, the only applicable access permissions are the typical access permissions of the underlying operating system. This makes SQLite a poor choice for applications that require multiple users with special access permissions.

**Security:** A database engine that uses a server can, in some instances, provide better protection from bugs in the client application than a serverless database like SQLite. For example, stray pointers in a client cannot corrupt memory on the server. Also, because a server is a single persistent process, a client-server database cancontrol data access with more precision than a serverless database, allowing for more fine-grained locking and better concurrency.

Comment: Read those disadvantages several times if necessary. Then install PostgreSQL server on your developer machine! (Unless production will be  something truly tiny, see NixonSparrow's answer).

Comment: You can use Docker to run a pg database. And configuring will take only creating env variables. Docker is a thing)

Comment: I didn't mean to imply how to install/run it.  Just use it.

Comment: @nigel222 yeah, i mean Docker makes it easy to deliver a nice database

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you recommend any database that is free and good for me?

Answer (score 0):

It depends where are you going to host it. Some servers do not accept `SQLite3` as database and require something more complicated as `PostgreSQL` (like `Heroku`). But if you are hosting by yourself (Rapsberry Pi for instance) then it's going to be fine and simple, if the site is going to have small traffic.

Comment: I'd never even thought of running Django on an RPi. But yes, a good reason for SQLite.

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you recommend any database that is free and good for me?

Comment: You can try `PostgreSQL`, it's usually recommended (i.e. given `Heroku`).

Comment: PostgreSQL is open-source and completely free. It is used by wide community and regulary updated. Feel free to use it